# How can I test that static files are served by WebServer not Django?

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a set-up with Apache and Django (actually, its AWS Elastic Beanstalk that provides Apache).
I've set up static files as you might expect, collected static and so on. I've also set up Apache (Elastic Beanstalk) to serve static files.

However, my question is this - how can I test that static files are indeed being served up by Apache (and not hitting Django)? I don't mean "look at log file here", or "delete this file and see what happens" - I mean a real test. So, for instance, is there some aspect of the HTTP headers that will allow me to distinguish if a file is served by Django via Apache, or via Apache only?

Comment: Why is verification via log files not a "real test"?

Comment: Django doesn't serve static files when DEBUG is False. So if you're seeing static files in production, they're served by the web server.

Comment: Having tried with both DEBUG False and DEBUG True, static files get served in both cases

Comment: @mbaird - testing via log files relies on the log level having been set, and Django definitely logging static access for one thing (i.e. not an independent test). Secondly, makes remote testing (i.e. not on the instance running Django) tricky - i.e. need log access remotely.

Answer (score 3):

You may look at **Server** response header.

This header cames from Django:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/static/file.txt -I --stderr - | grep Server
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
```

This header cames from Apache:

```
$ curl http://www.apache.org/img/asf_logo.png -I --stderr - | grep Server
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Alas, on Elastic Beanstalk the header every time (in this case for a static CSS file) is:
Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 ... would seem to suggest Django serving it?

Comment: @KevinD, I guess so. Could you check a header on file which 100% served by Apache?

Comment: When files are served by Apache, header is the same: Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10

Comment: Also i would suggest you put some custom header through `Middleware.process_response` and check it.